# How to view code coverage for specific test case method using Jacoco?

Tags: java, testing, ant, code-coverage, jacoco

I'm wondering if there is a way to view or generate the code coverage for each of the test cases in a test class using Jacoco and preferably Ant.

Right now I generate a coverge report with the information about the total coverage etc for the package and the classes which are tested. But what I want is to generate information about how much my method testcase1() covered and later on how much my testcase2() method covered.

I can parse the test class and seperate the test cases from eachother and for example execute each and everyone by themselves I assume. But, is there a better way to accomplish this?

Is there other libraries etc out there which do this, I haven't found any yet but maybe someone know of any?

Basically what I want to do is to identify which test cases increases the statement/Branch coverage.

Ciao!

Comment: Do you use Eclipse?  If so, you can use the Emma plugin and then run the tests using the Coverage option - which will generate the reports in an Eclipse view for you.

Comment: Yes I'm using Eclipse but I would like to get this information dynamically through an ANT script or equal, and not having to click my way through it...

Comment: Have done this using Cobertura but not Jacoco but run for the entire project not just a single class.  Good luck!

Comment: HI, Did you find a way to do it, Even I am trying the same